# getting a repository for projects

Tags: repository

When I was on an army programming course me and my friends used SVN with a repository we had. I wanna set up a repository so that I can work on my projects without having to worry about moving my files from pc to pc and working with the right version.

If there's something you can recommend and what source control program I can use I'd love that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two commonly-used repository hosting sites are Github (https://github.com/) and Bitbucket (http://bitbucket.org). They use git (Bitbucket also supports Mercurial) instead of SVN, which is similar but has a slightly different workflow. These two services are easy to get started with and have great tutorials. And repositories are free!

Comment: BitBucket also supports Mercurial, another DVCS.

Comment: Thanks for the info! git is sorta like svn that it's like an addon to your ide so you can like commit and whatever straight from your workspace right?

Comment: It's not an add-on, no - neither is SVN. There are tools and plugins you can use as graphical interfaces to your IDE that use git, same as you can do in SVN. Git allows commits, pulls, pushes, branches, etc, just like SVN.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Install, configure and run own instance of SVN-server on own host
- Move to [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/), which offer natural SVN-hosting
- Select any other [SVN-hosting](https://www.google.ru/search?q=svn-hosting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=pb9XVcynL4H2sgHh2ICIAQ)
- Create Git-repos on GitHub, but use SVN-gate (special SVN-URL) and SVN-clients